# Restore de apenas uma tabela - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Como posso realizar o restore de apenas um tabela de um banco para outro?

Criei o backup da tabela a partir do seguinte comando no CMD:

```
pg_dump -f C:\Backup\Backup_table.backup -t public.lotesretornosuprimento -d BancoDados
```

Porém não estou encontrando como posso fazer o restore dessa tabela apenas

Comment: https://makandracards.com/zeroglosa/27675-gerar-e-restaurar-backup-de-apenas-uma-tabela-postgres veja se isso o ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você fez o dump somente de uma tabela, o `pg_restore` só possuiria um objeto para restaurar. De qualquer maneira existe o parâmetro `-t` para definir as tabelas que serão restauradas.

```
pg_restore -t public.lotesretornosuprimento -d BancoDados C:\Backup\Backup_table.backup
```

Caso queira restaurar somente os dados, sem enviar os comandos para criar o schema, utilize o parâmetro `-a`.

Se for necessário recriar os objetos antes de restaurar use o parâmetro `-c`.

Mais detalhes sobre o `pg_restore` podem ser encontrados na documentação do postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html